# Check object existence in mongo using gopkg.in/mgo.v2

Tags: mongodb, go

I am looking for convinient way to check if object already exists in collection. For now the only way that i have found is

```
type result interface{}
var res result

err := col.Find(bson.M{"title": "title1"}).One(&res)
if err != nil {
    if err.Error() == "not found" {
        log.Println("No such document")
    } else {
        log.Println("err occured", err)
    }
}
```

I dont want to create variable res, in case if object exists, it can be very heavy document with a lot of fields.
I wish there would be another way, some Check() function which will just return bool value.. 
Basically I only need to know that object already stored in collection, I dont need itself

Comment: to anyone here later on also make sure you use mgo.ErrNotFound instead of == "not found"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you have to use $exists

Syntax: { field: { $exists:  } }

For more details

http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/exists/

Comment: I need to check that object with FIELD value X already exists; $exists will find objects with FIELD no matter what its value. And again, I only need to know that object already is in db, I dont need itself

Comment: Do you mean you want to check if the field with certain value exist in a collection ?

Comment: yes, you have formulated it way better than I did :)

Comment: you can simply use count greater than 0 here is the code  db.colleaction.count({filed:value})>0

Comment: db.colleaction.count({filed:value})>0  how we do this in golang using gopkg.in/mgo.v2 ?

Answer (score 11):

```
count, err = collection.Find(bson.M{field: value}).Count()
```

Comment: NOTE: You have to set `db.SetSafe(&mgo.Safe{})` first for this to work - otherwise it will always return 0 and nil!

Comment: This is not a good way, if you have millions of documents, it will take a high cost and too much time to count the whole collection, and in the end, you really don't care about how many documents is there, but just if any document exists.

Answer (score 1):

in the [Official Mongo Driver](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-go-driver) you can get count of documents with specific key using **CountDocuments** function :

```golang
count, err := collection.CountDocuments(context.TODO(), bson.D{{"key", "value"}})
```